# Apache POI - Can I somehow speed up resizing of excel columns?

Tags: apache-poi

```
public void resizeColumns(SXSSFSheet worksheet, SXSSFRow row) {
    for (int i = baseDoc.length(); i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        worksheet.setColumnWidth(i, 256);
    }
}
```

So, this is really simple method which sets column widths. Problem is that I have about 5000 columns. Resizing of first 700-1000 columns take few seconds. But then this iteration is getting really slow. For example, usually I have to generate Excel with about 3000 columns and I need to resize them. Resizing takes 2-3 minutes. Without resizing is xlsx generated in few seconds!

I have already tried to set default width for worksheet: `worksheet.setDefaultColumnWidth()` and then simple resized only rest (which was about 10 columns). It was really speedy - but this is not good solution for me, because `setDefaultColumnWidth()` accepts int as parameter (it means number of characters) and I have to have column widths less than one character.

Comment: What version of POI are you using? And have you tried a recent nightly build? Only there have been a few column related performance fixes of late, it's possible one of them will help for your case

Comment: Hi Gagravarr, 
firstly thank you for answer. So, when I was wondering and trying to solve this problem, I have upgraded to 3.9 version of POI - but nothing happens. I have checked release notes about 3.10 beta, but I don't see anything what can help me there.

Comment: Try a recent nightly build just in case, I've definitely seen something go past lately around column operation performace